# AWS EC2 instance for multiple accounts

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, instance, sharing

I have an EC2 instance which I want to share with other people. Can someone help me with this?

Whenever other people log in to their account, they want to see my EC2 instance in their dashboard.

Comment: They will never see your instance in their EC2 console unless you grant them access to your account. But what do you mean by "share with other people"? What do you want them to be able to do with the instance, aside from seeing it in a list?

Comment: Yes, I want to share access, they can work from that EC2 instance

Comment: I don't understand the downvotes.  This is a particularly legitimate and perhaps even common scenario.  You got 4 people working on the same team and they all need to login to the virtual machine to work together on a codebase / project and access shared results.

Comment: I could see this being needed for continuity purposes. What if the person who created the instance dies? There should be a way for others to access it with the same capability.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use IAM roles to give access to EC2 instances. Once you create the user then add the user to a group that has access to the EC2 instance.

Answer (score 1):

An Amazon EC2 instance is just a **virtual machine**. AWS will help you provision the computer, but it is running whatever operating system you choose to install. From that point onwards, you are in complete control of the computer, not AWS.

For **Windows** instances, EC2 will generate a **random Administrator password**. You can use it to login to the computer and do standard Windows stuff, like create additional users, assign them permissions, etc. Or, just give your users the Administrator password and they can login as that user themselves.

For **Linux**, you SSH to the machine using a **Keypair** that you nominate when the instance is started. You can either give other people that keypair, or [add other users to the instance](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/managing-users.html).

So, if your goal is to "share access, they can work from that EC2 instance", just do it like any other Internet-accessible computer. The fact that it is on EC2 makes no difference.